# Quels sont les noms des outils d'un « carpenter » et de quel métier s'agit-il ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, professions

[image]

Pouvez-vous svp m'aider à identifier ces outils et à comprendre à quel métier on associe généralement le *carpenter* dans ce contexte ?

- *Quels sont les noms courants de ces outils (1-7) ?* En regardant certaines listes, j'ai pu lire l'[*avion de cric de
  main*](http://fr.dreamstime.com/photo-stock-homme-travaillant-avec-l-avion-de-cric-de-main-image61016585) (*homme travaillant avec*...) et la [*règle de pliage*](http://fr.dreamstime.com/illustration-stock-r%C3%A8gle-de-pliage-image51114681) ;
  en comparant avec l'article *Wikipédia* sur le [*charpentier*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charpentier), le
  [*menuisier*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuisier) ou l'[ébéniste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89b%C3%A9niste), il ne m'a pas semblé que cela
  corresponde à aucun des outils traditionnels. Ailleurs on trouve des [documents](http://collections.banq.qc.ca/bitstream/52327/2064901/1/478224.jpg) anciens avec un lexique idiosyncratique ou régional...
- Sur l'image on pouvait lire le mot [*carpenter*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/carpenter/568694) en anglais. Vu le
  lexique, et à l'évidence le contexte de l'artisanat d'autrefois, à
  quel métier fait-on généralement référence ici en français ?

Comment: La liste des outils en français est disponible ici : http://fr.dreamstime.com/illustration-stock-charpentier-avec-le-bois-de-construction-et-les-outils-professionnels-image55401456

Comment: Ah, ok, ils ont passé le _jack plane_ au robot plutôt qu'au _rabot_...

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà Bien dit/trouvé! But considering the amount of effort put into completing his/her assignment, I think the OP will (or at least should) be happy with a less than perfect score on it.  Funny too, imo, how the robot didn’t generate “moustachu” (or at least “moustaché” [sic]) for “m[o]ustached”!

Answer (score 5):

For me:

- Top left: *des clous*
- Middle left: *une hache*, *une masse* and *un marteau*
- Bottom left: *une scie à bois* and *une scie à métaux*
- Top center: I don't recognize it... Maybe *une caisse à outils*?
- Top right: *du bois* (?)
- Middle right: *un mètre*
- Bottom right: *un rabot*.

This is very specific and the picture is not very clear.

Comment: That's a *rabot* (a.k.a. avion de cric) at the bottom right.

Comment: top center : "une caisse à outil" oui. And bottom right "un rabot" yes.

Comment: On peut deviner une _poutre_, deux _planches_ et une _bille_ de bois (du _bois rond_)...

Comment: Middle right, I would use, more precisely: *un mètre pliant*.

Comment: +1 It’s probably just my screen’s color settings, but I see the tool between the *hache* and the *marteau* as having a lighter colored *tête*, which makes me think that it could be *un maillet en caoutchouc*  (ou *plastique*).”

Answer (score 1):

A carpenter : dans ce contexte ça semble être un menuisier plutôt qu'un charpentier.

1. Des clous.
2. Une caisse à outils.
3. Du bois:

   - Des poutres.
   - (je ne comprends pas bien ce qui est représenté)
   - Des planches.
4. Un mètre pliant (ou simplement : un mètre).
5. Un rabot.
6. Des scies:

   - Une scie égoïne (ou simplement : une scie).
   - Une scie à métaux.
7. - Une hache.
   - Un maillet.
   - Un marteau.

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas ajouter une ligne pour expliquer pourquoi le contexte vous fait dire qu'il s'agit du menuisier plutôt que du charpentier ? Merci. p.s. si on imagine que les planches et la poutre ont une profondeur, alors il en irait de même pour ce truc rond, un tronc d'arbre, un billot, une bille, du bois rond etc. mais l'illustration a ses limites.

Answer (score 0):

"**Carpenter**" signifiant "**Charpentier**", de quoi d'autre pourrait-il s'agir, concernant quelqu'un qui manipule du bois avec des scies et des clous? Ou alors y a-t-il un piège qui m'aurait échappé?

Comment: Menuisier, ébéniste ?